# Swype within Stackexchange loses some function.

Tags: bug, mobile-web

I communicate with Stackexchange via my telephone (Galaxy S5 / Verizon). I use a virtual-keyboard facilitator called Swype (a product of Nuance). Swype works fine for me -- except when I use it in the Stackexchange environment. Ordinarily, I am able to select limited portions of text and do with it what I will; in Stackexchange, it's either all or nothing. The selection seems to work in that it highlights the text-of-interest, but when I go to move it, it just stays there like a bump on a log. I assume that the fault lies in the Stackexchange, since it is only there that the failure occurs for me.